# How to know when itś the current last line in the console with popen on ruby

Tags: ruby, popen, open4

I'm trying to make a program with action cable that can start a specific process in the terminal and interact with it with commands given by the user. So far I've managed to run a command in the terminal by installing open4 with popen (The default ruby popen wasn´t working correctly for some reason) like this:

```bash
[6]  development  (main)> pid, stdin, stdout, stderr = Open4::popen4 "./my_program"
=> [37158, #<IO:fd 41>, #<IO:fd 43>, #<IO:fd 46>]
[7]  development  (main)> stdout.gets
=> " __  __       _       _____          \n"
[8]  development  (main)> stdout.gets
=> "|  \\/  | __ _| |_ ___|  ___|   _ _ __ v 0.17 \n"
[9]  development  (main)> stdout.gets
=> "| |\\/| |/ _` | __/ _ \\ |_ | | | | '_ \\   \n"
[10]  development  (main)> stdout.gets
=> "| |  | | (_| | ||  __/  _|| |_| | | | |  \n"
[11]  development  (main)> stdout.gets
=> "|_|  |_|\\__,_|\\__\\___|_|   \\__,_|_| |_|  \n"
[12]  development  (main)> stdout.gets
=> "\n"
[13]  development  (main)> stdout.gets
=> "\n"
[14]  development  (main)> stdout.gets
=> "\n"
```

That works lovely, but if I try to do another `stdout.gets` it just "freezes", it's probably not frozen and just waits indefinitely for something to give me, `stdout.eof?` returns `false` so that isn´t useful.

I need to send the program's output to the user, but I also need to maintain the program running to accept further instructions from the user. How can I know when I've reached the last line of the current terminal output?

Comment: _"How can I know when I've reached the last line?"_ – you can't. Think of programs like [top](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_(software)) which keep generating output without any user input. Try to handle the two directions (user → stdin and stdout → user) independently.

Comment: Another options is if you have control of the program output, then make it send an ending marker at end of output. Then you can just watch for it to know when the output is finished.

Comment: Thanks! I still don't understand why I can't know it, it clearly doesn't have anything more on the screen so it seems to me I should be able to see that, but I was able to solve it with an ending marker.